# Accessing sql 2008 database through visual studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Hey guys I have what should be a simple question, but I am new to C# so I am having just a little problem.  I am using the following connection:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=myservername\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Names;");
```

I have also tried to include user id and password but my login always fails.

I think this is because I am not really sure what username and password to use.

With my sql server I am using windows authentication... if that helps.

does anyone know which username and password I should be using? or another way to do this?

I have seen that I may need to turn remote access on in my sql settings, can anyone tell me how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection string should specify that integrated authentication (Windows authentication) has to be used. Otherwise it tries to do SQL user/password authentication, which is disabled on the SQL Server by default, and if enabled it doesn't authenticate against Windows users.

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Remote access is only required if your application and the SQL Server Express instance aren't on the same machine (which is why the sample connection string here has a `.` for the server name, which represents the local server).

Comment: This is what you need or Trusted_Connection=True; which means the same thing, http://www.connectionstrings.com/, specifying the user and password only works for SQL auth not windows auth

Comment: True, they are in fact interchangeable, but `Trusted_Connection` seems to be an ODBC relict so I avoid it.